# Is it possible to draw a parabola on a curve object in Geometry nodes?(3.3)

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

Now I was able to generate Particle Hair

I want to change it to a parabolic shape
[image]
in this way
[image]

Bent curves don't have to work in simulation and dynamics
But I couldn't come up with an idea
Please lend me your wisdom